# Can I keep Windows 10 Home from updating on any network other than my home network?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, windows-update, mobile-phone

I use my laptop (Windows 10 Home) 95% of the time away from home.  Over 50% of that time it is using my iPhone data plan.  When auto-updates hit, my bandwidth is wasted, my computer is bogged down, and I risk destroying my HDD if I close up and go home while it is functioning.

I have turned off the update service for now.  I am hoping there is some way to tell it not to do updates when on wifi unless it is connected to my home router. I really don't want to have updates turned off, but if that's what it takes...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT 1:
The iPhone is being used as just another WIFI device as far as the computer can see.

EDIT 2:
I tried following instructions for declaring a WIFI as metered connection for W8.1, but it doesn't work for 10. .. Still searching

Edit 3: 
It appears that I must be connected to the wifi in question in order to change it to metered connection.  I'll have to remember to do that whenever I connect.  :(

Thank you for your helps!  I am grateful.

Final Edit:

Thank you everyone for your input.  I needed it to find the ultimate answer to my question.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Windows Update by default behaves differently on a metered connection.

Comment: Clarification would be nice but I suspect that the OP is hotspotting his phone. I don't think the computer can tell that is a metered connection. I think it just sees a wifi connection.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure what is not clear.  My phone becomes a WIFI and my computer sees it as it does any WIFI anywhere.  While I have heard the term, "metered connection," I have been unable to find any settings for it in Windows.  My apologies if I am unclear as I am new to Windows as I left back when Vista was released.

Comment: @EBGreen - He can configure it as a metered connection.  Once configured Windows will always treat it as a metered connection.

Comment: I'll search for configuring a metered connection.  Thank you

Comment: Easy :) set your "Update check" for a specific time, when you are usauly in your home..

Comment: in Windows 10?  Where?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you, where?! because I still have win8.1, in my windows, navigate to control panel > windows update then choose "change setting" and set the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a learning what to search for, I came to a resolution.

1. Change updates to "Schedule a reboot time"
   `Settings`, `Update and security`, `Windows Update`, `Advanced Options`, `Notify to schedule restart`
2. Turn on "update sharing"
   (From the same place step 1 left you) `Choose how updates are delivered`, `On`, `PCs on my local network`
   (This helps family update but not the Internet)
3. Set all Wi-Fi connections to "metered connections" except for my home connection.
   A) Turn On Wi-Fi
   `Settings`, `Network & Internet`, `Wi-Fi`, `On`
   B) Set Home network settings:
   Select your home network Wi-Fi and connect.
   `Advanced Options` Set metered connection `Off`
   C) Set visited network settings: 
   (You will have to do this at the remote locations.  You can only edit Wi-Fi connections while connected to the router.)
   Select your visited network Wi-Fi and connect.
   `Advanced Options` Set metered connection `On`
   D) Repeat for each additional remote Wi-Fi you connect to until all have been set.

At least in theory, or until the next update (which ever comes first) your updates should leave you alone until you are connected to your home network.

I tested this using my iPhone connection.  I started the Windows update service and chose to update windows.  In a few moments, it responded with a message that it could not download my updates at this time.

I connected to my home router, clicked the `Update Now` button and got no messages at all.  I assume it found nothing and closed.  It never notified me to reboot.

If you desire to turn off updates for a period of time, such as for a business trip or vacation, etc., you can turn off Windows Updates in Services.

To access Services, go to `Settings` and in the search box, (top right), type "services" and press `Enter`.

Select `View local services` and the services panel will open in the background.  Minimize `Settings` window and scroll down to `Windows Update`

Right click `Windows Update` and choose `Properties`
Click `Stop` if available, and then change the startup type from `Manual` to `Disabled`.

To turn it back on, change it back to `Manual`. Click `Start` to reactivate it.  You should be good to go from now on.